# I have set up the sample app on google cloud platform succesfully. After running a test, I am now wondering where the assets that I create are stored?

Tags: storage, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created a hyperledger google cloud platform installation. 
Secondly I then installed the hyperledger sample network. All this went fine. Also the asset creation went find after I created the static IP on the VM. I now am wondering where my "hello world" asset remained.

I saw that a verification peer should have a /var/hyperledger...
Doing the default google cloud platform installation, what are my peers? This seems all to be hidden. Does that mean that the data is just "out there"? 
I am checking how to tweak the google cloud platform installation to have private data storage now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the Google cloud platform and  using VM to run all your things. then all your information is being stored in the persistant disk you selected while install the platform.

Regarding Assets, you can not see physical the assets in fabric, those are stored in Level DB or CouchDb. default configuration of the fabric is LevelDB. 
if you configure CouchDb then you can see the data in URL. Hope, this helps.